# Minimise $a + b + c + d$ s.t. $a^3+b^3=c^3+d^3$

Tags: optimization

a, b, c, and d are all different positive integers. I've tried googling optimisation and constrained optimisation, but I've not found anything applicable as yet.

EDIT:

I tried using Lagrange mulipliers, but hit a wall:

$$f(a,b,c,d) = a+b+c+d$$

$$g(a,b,c,d) = a^3+b^3-c^3-d^3$$

Lagrange gives the system:

$$f_i = \lambda g_i, i = a,b,c,d$$

$$1 = \lambda(3i^2), i=a,b \\ 1 = \lambda(-3i^2), i=c,d$$

(Equations $1-4$)

$$a^3+b^3-c^3-d^3=0$$

(Eq $5$)

This would give $a=b$ and $c=d$, but this would break the constraint that they are all different, so don't know if Lagrange can help with this.

EDIT: (in progress)

$1729 = 1^3+12^3 = 9^3 + 10^3$ is the solution, as pointed out by Macavity, but I am seeking a proof of this.

Comment: Try looking into Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Cheyne H

Comment: If you use Lagrange, the best you get are real number solutions.  Further, you need to put in all constraints, including the positivity ones and that they need to be distinct.  Not worth it, IMHO.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure and I have ground to a halt with Lagrange (see EDIT). (+1 for info on constraints).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have heard of a rather famous anecdote about the Ramanujan and the number $1729$, you would know that this is the least number expressible as the sum of two positive cubes in two different ways, i.e. $1729 = 1^3+12^3 = 9^3 + 10^3$.  So the answer you seek is $1+12+9+10 = 32$.

Apart from enumerating and testing numbers, I see no fast way of finding this answer...

Comment: It's clear that this minimizes $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3$.  Is it clear that it minimizes $a+b+c+d$?  My guess is that you'll not only need the $1729$ anecdote, but a bound on the next such solution.

Comment: @AWalker Well the next one is $4104 = (2^3 + 16^3) = (9^3 + 15^3)$, but somehow this enumeration approach doesn't seem satisfying.  From http://oeis.org/A001235

Comment: Other than enumeration, I am not sure if you will find a way.  The general form you postulate doesn't work for $20683 = (10^3 + 27^3) = (19^3 + 24^3)$ or for $39312 = (2^3 + 34^3)=(15^3 + 33^3)$.  I am sure if you test more solutions, you will find many more counter-examples.

Comment: Thanks for the first counter-example (+1). The second isn't a counter-example, as the $4104$ solution fits my postulate and is a lower solution for $n=2$.

Comment: It turns out the question has been posed before in a different form, with the same answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487537/proof-that-1729-is-the-smallest-taxicab-number

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, good catch, it has cropped up at least twice that I have seen, with different parts in each question. People getting more creative, and harder to spot these i suppose.