# Ramanujan's proof that Ta(2)=1729 (i.e., that 1729 is the smallest non-trivial taxicab number)

Tags: number-theory

On [another thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487537/proof-that-1729-is-the-smallest-taxicab-number) someone posted a problem from their math homework: to prove that 1729 is the smallest non-trivial taxicab number (or, if you prefer, that $Ta(2)=1729$). Commenters suggested simply brute forcing it, which I take as an indication that there's no elementary proof. But do we know how Ramanujan knew? Did we brute force it before the advent of computers?

Comment: We do not know how Ramanujan knew. He discovered mathematical results which seem impossible to find without modern theory or computers. The question is now answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487537/proof-that-1729-is-the-smallest-taxicab-number),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think brute force was probably the way to go, once you had noticed that 1729 had the desired property. You would only need to check at most 12 x 12 / 2 = 72 sums as floor (cube root 1729) is 12.