# How to calculate $\operatorname{taxicab}(3,8,2)$ (sum of 8 cubes in two different ways)

Tags: number-theory

Could someone explain me how I can calculate $\operatorname{taxicab}(3,8,2)$?

$\operatorname{taxicab}(3,8,2)$ is the smallest natural number that can be written in $2$ different ways as a sum of $8$ powers $3$.

For instance:

\begin{align}\operatorname{taxicab}(4,3,2) &= 2673\\
&= 7^4 + 4^4 + 2^4 (or 2401+256+16)
&= 6^4 + 6^4 + 3^4 (or 1296+1296+81)
\end{align}

How can I calculate $\operatorname{taxicab}(3,8,2)$?

This notion is a generalization of the notion of [Taxicab number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number), which is mentioned in the famous story about Hardy and Ramanujan. See also [Proof that $1729$ is the smallest taxicab number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487537/proof-that-1729-is-the-smallest-taxicab-number)

Comment: amm ok, it's my first time.

Comment: If you mean the "taxicab" norm (i.e. the $1$-norm), then you simply have to add the absolute value of the coordinates.

Comment: isn't standard?? sorry, I want to say:
the smallest number that can be written in two different ways as a sum of 8 powers 3.

Comment: $8$ positive cubes? $6+1729$.

Comment: I'm guessing that [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number) has something to do with it.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand you, your answer is a bit short.
for examplo:
 x1^3 + x2^3 + x3^3 + x4^3 + x5^3 + x6^3 +x7^3 +x8^3   =  y1^3 + y2^3 + y3^3 + y4^3 + y5^3 + y6^3 +y7^3 + y8^3.
I mean this with to say "as a sum of 8 powers 3 or as a sum 8 positive cubes"

Comment: I think it will be better to write cubes instead of powers of $3$ to remove ambiguity.

Comment: The question is very innovative. Did you make it yourself ?

Comment: I have added link to to the Wikipedia article. You post has already four close votes and three downvotes. One of the reason might be missing context. You have already improved it by adding the definition. Perhaps adding something about origin of the problem or related problems would be an improvement, too. So I have added information which I was aware of. Feel free to revert the changes if you feel that does not fit your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\eqalign{132=1^3 + 1^3 + 1^3 + 1^3 + 1^3 + 1^3 + 1^3 + 5^3 (or 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+125) =1^3 + 2^3 + 2^3 + 2^3 + 2^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + 4^3 (or 1+8+8+8+8+8+27+64)}$$

This can be found by a recursive computation.

Let $N(x,m)$ be the number of different ways to write $x$ as the (unordered) sum of $m$ positive cubes. Then $N(x,m) = M(x,m,\lfloor x^{1/3} \rfloor)$ where $M(x,m,n)$ is the number of different ways to write $x = a_1^3  + \ldots + a_m^3$ with $1 \le a_1 \le \ldots \le a_m \le n$.

$$\eqalign{M(x,0,n) &= \cases{1 & if $x=0$\cr 0 & otherwise}\cr 
M(x,m,n) &= \sum_{y=1}^{\min(n, \lfloor x^{1/3} \rfloor)} M(x - y^3, m-1, y)}$$

Comment: Thanks very much.
But I don't understand very well.
mm.. could you tell me the first steps, please?
for example:
If "x" we don't know, and "m" is 8 not? so... M(x,8,n) then if "y=1", in the first step, M(x-1³,8-1,1) not? but what is "n"?
sorry if I don't understand well.

Comment: and.. min(n,⌊x^1/3⌋) I don't understand that, because I don't know what is "n" and "x" is the result.
sorry, I am starting in this.

Comment: In order to find, say, $M(132,8,5)$, you'll need $M(131, 7,1)$ and $M(124, 7, 2)$ and ... $M(7, 7, 5)$.  For each of those you'll need some $M(x,6,n)$, and so on.   It looks like a lot of computation, but it's easy with a computer.  You could even do it on a spreadsheet.  The trick is to remember $M(x,y,n)$ once you compute it, because you'll probably need it for a later step.

Comment: How did you get this idea ?

Comment: A standard technique.

Comment: yes, I understand this answer but, what is the minimum between "n" and ⌊x1/3⌋? I ask that because in your answer you say M(x,m,⌊x1/3⌋)  where M(x,m,n) so.. I think that ⌊x1/3⌋ = n.

Comment: You can't take $y > x^{1/3}$ because that would make $x - y^3$ negative.  You can't take $y > n$ because $M(x,m,n)$ is supposed to have $a_m \le n$.

Comment: ok, thanks so much,
If I would like calculate for example taxicab(4,8,2) I only have to change "1/3" by "1/4" or it would has other technique?

Comment: And I think another thing.
if the taxicab(2) is 1729 because 10^3 + 7^3 = 12^3 + 1^3 for this reasoning the taxicab(3) is 1730 adding up 1^3 both sides and it is not like that, because taxicab(3) is 4104.

Comment: Who said taxicab(3) is $4104$? Actually it should be $251 = 2^3 + 3^3 + 6^3 = 1^3 + 5^3 + 5^3$.

Comment: $4104$ is not a sum of three positive cubes at all.

Comment: take a look http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaxicabNumber.html